# How to make assumptions in Prolog

Tags: prolog

If I have a database of facts and rules, lets say

```
person(mary).
employee(bob).

not_a_robot(X) :- person(X).
```

Is there a way to *assume* rules for the (thread local) context of a query?
something like:

```
?- assume((person(X) :- employee(X)), not_a_robot(Y))
X = mary ;
X = bob.
```

Such that only the call that made the assumption would see the updated view of the database.

Not sure if `asserting` and then `retracting` from the database would have this effect? (AFAIK using `assert` would also mean that all predicates would also be required to be marked as dynamic)

Comment: Isn't an `assert` followed by a `retract` what you want?

Comment: Not sure if there is a standard (special) approach for this. Also as far as I am aware assert requires all predicates to be dynamic, however I don't think that a predicate definition would ever need to change _during execution_... ie it is thread local...

Comment: As I don't fully understand what you are trying to do I can't give an answer. What gives me more possible insight into your problem is this comment `Isn't an assert followed by a retract what you want? `. If that is correct then take a look at the asserta/2 use case in this [example](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/using-call-cleanup-2-trying-to-understand-when-to-use-it-or-others-predicates-of-the-same-intention/657/6?u=ericgt) of use_cases for [setup_call_cleanup/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=setup_call_cleanup/3). Let me know - If that works, I can make answer

Comment: See the following example and its bibliographic references for some ideas on assumptions: https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/tree/master/examples/assumptions You can run the example with most Prolog systems.